# android translate string with variables

Tags: android, xml, translate

good morning,

i have an android app with a german and english language xml file.
now i would like to set and text view like this:

"Hello User x, hello world y."
"Hallo Benutzer x, hallo welt y."

for x and y i would like set an variable.
how can i translate this text for both languages with dynamic variables ?

Comment: link **NOT** for translation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html    but if you want to change language of text shown in form inputs use this

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: if u have fixed number of words to be translated. make a java.util.Map<String,  String> where you can fetch german value for a given english key

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question seems unclear but from my understanding I am suggesting you the solution.

If you want to pass a dynamic argument to string you can do this by bellow example.

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

In this example, the format string has two arguments: %1$s is a string and %2$d is a decimal number. You can format the string with arguments from your application like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```

If you wish more look at: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: Can I add those vars from xml layout rather than from java?

Answer (score 0):

"Hello User %1$s, hello world %2$s." 
"Hallo Benutzer %1$s, hallo welt %2$s." 
In code then simply call getString(R.string.your_string, yourName, yourWorld) where yourName and yourWorld are String variables.

If you need to know where to store the strings see the answer of Devendra Singh.

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way in google translation.

[Just copy the strings from English resource and go to google translation][1]r.com/UQBXd.png

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).